# Run makefile if it exists, otherwise run extension specific command with vimscript

Tags: makefile, vim

I want to map <kbd>F9</kbd> to run the makefile in the current or parent directories, and if no makefile is found, run something based on the file extension.

I tried doing this:

```
function! Runf9()
  if filereadable("./Makefile")
    make
  elseif (&filetype == "tex")
    execute("!pdflatex " + bufname("%"))
  endif
endfunction
nmap <silent> <F9> :call Runf9()<CR>
```

But this only works for makefiles in the current directory, I don't know how to search for them in the parent directories, it also does not work for `.tex` files when there is no `Makefile`.

Comment: `filereadable` takes a path... give it a path of `"../Makefile"` for the parent directory? What is filetype for your `.tex` file? `tex`? `plaintex`? `latex`?

Comment: @EtanReisner I also the parent of the parent directory and so on, the tex files have extension .tex and contain latex

Comment: I didn't ask about the file extension. That's not what `&filetype` is telling you. `&filetype` is the internal filetype name that vim considers the file. If you want to check the extension you need to do that differently.

Comment: How far up the path hierarchy do you want to go? Not all the way to the root clearly. How do you decide? You can loop arbitrarily far if you want.

Comment: @EtanReisner `:set filetype?` returns `filetype=tex`, as for makefiles, I think 3 directories is appropiate

Comment: So loop adding `../` until you are done. And that second check should be working. Have you checked the filetype in the file you said it wasn't working for?

Comment: @EtanReisner When I run `echo ("!pdflatex " + bufname("%"))` in vim, the output is simply `0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `+` in the line with execute is exchanged with a `.` it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can do (both up- and downward-) file searches via the `findfile()` function.

As you've already found out, string concatenation has to be done with `.`, not with `+`, which is for numerical addition only.